# What is difference between PermissionAndroid and react-native-react-native-permissions?

Tags: react-native

Is there any difference between `react-native-permissions` and `PermissionsAndroid` ?

Which of them would be better to use for requesting user permissions and access device features like, `contacts, taking photos and videos, gallery picures files and videos, microphone, locations and etc`?

**I need for both IOS and Android.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PermissionsAndroid` only applies to Android so you won't be able to request iOS permissions with it. `react-native-permissions` seems to support a good amount of permissions for both platforms, although not all.

Comment: Which of them would be better ?

Comment: Obviously `react-native-permissions` if you want to be able to request on both platforms.

Comment: May there be an auto request for IOS

Comment: Yes, on iOS you have to indicate which permissions your app will need in the info.plist file. It will then prompt the user automatically when these permissions are needed, but with `PermissionsAndroid`, you have no way of checking if they've been granted on iOS.